# Unity Android Build Error Duplicate classes

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Unity version: Unity 2020.1.17f

After build game for Android, I got these erros

In Player Settings I checked Custom Main Manifest, Custom Launcher Manifest, Custom Launcher Gradle Template and Custom Gralde Properties Template

I tried to everything, please help

This error happens when I made Android Resolver

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback$Stub found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback$Stub$Proxy found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsService found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsService$Stub found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsService$Stub$Proxy found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.IPostMessageService found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.IPostMessageService$Stub found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.IPostMessageService$Stub$Proxy found in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.RemoteActionCompatParcelizer found in modules core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.2.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.3.2-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.3.2:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.2.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.3.2-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.3.2:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.2.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.3.2-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.3.2:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.2.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.3.2-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.3.2:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.2.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.3.2-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.3.2:)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.2.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.2.0) and jetified-androidx.core.core-1.3.2-runtime.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.3.2:)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimatorRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnyRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnyThread found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ArrayRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AttrRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.BinderThread found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.BoolRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.CallSuper found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.CheckResult found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ColorInt found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ColorLong found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ColorRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ContentView found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.DimenRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.Dimension found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.DrawableRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.FloatRange found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.FontRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.FractionRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.GuardedBy found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.HalfFloat found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.IdRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.InspectableProperty found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.InspectableProperty$EnumEntry found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.InspectableProperty$FlagEntry found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.InspectableProperty$ValueType found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.IntDef found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.IntRange found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.IntegerRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.InterpolatorRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.Keep found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.LayoutRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.LongDef found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.MainThread found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.MenuRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.NavigationRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.NonNull found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.Nullable found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.PluralsRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.Px found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.RawRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.RequiresApi found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.RequiresFeature found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.RequiresPermission found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.RequiresPermission$Read found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.RequiresPermission$Write found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.RestrictTo found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.RestrictTo$Scope found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.Size found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.StringDef found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.StringRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.StyleRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.StyleableRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.TransitionRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.UiThread found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.VisibleForTesting found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.WorkerThread found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.XmlRes found in modules annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.executor.ArchTaskExecutor found in modules core-runtime-2.0.1-runtime.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1) and jetified-androidx.arch.core.core-runtime-2.0.1-runtime.jar (:androidx.arch.core.core-runtime-2.0.1:)
  Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.executor.ArchTaskExecutor$1 found in modules core-runtime-2.0.1-runtime.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1) and jetified-androidx.arch.core.core-runtime-2.0.1-runtime.jar (:androidx.arch.core.core-runtime-2.0.1:)
  Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.executor.ArchTaskExecutor$2 found in modules core-runtime-2.0.1-runtime.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1) and jetified-androidx.arch.core.core-runtime-2.0.1-runtime.jar (:androidx.arch.core.core-runtime-2.0.1:)
  Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.executor.DefaultTaskExecutor found in modules core-runtime-2.0.1-runtime.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1) and jetified-androidx.arch.core.core-runtime-2.0.1-runtime.jar (:androidx.arch.core.core-runtime-2.0.1:)
  Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.executor.DefaultTaskExecutor$1 found in modules core<message truncated>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error often occurs when you import multiple SDKs with different versions of the Play Services Resolver.

**Solutions:**

1. Delete resolved libraries and resolve again

   - Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Delete Resolved Libraries
   - Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Resolve
2. Include SDKs again

   - Delete imported SDKs
   - Import SDKs again, but this time check the resolver for only one tool
   - Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Resolve
3. Manually delete duplicate classes (in worst case)

   - In Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Settings disable auto resolve.
   - Find in resources folder duplicate classes mentioned in log and delete them ( eg. delete 'androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar' and keep 'annotation-1.1.0.jar')

Answer (score 1):

For me the the only fix was:
1 - "Delete resolved libraries" in android resolver.
2 -  Delete all libraries from "Android" folder
3 - "Resolve" in android resolver

Answer (score 0):

**For Unity 2019.4 or lower version**

- Use Play Services Resolver to resolve the dependencies.
- `Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Resolve`
  [image]

**For Unity 2020+ versions**

- Use External Dependency Manager to resolve the dependencies.
- `Assets > External Dependency Manager > Android Resolver > Resolve`
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

I deleted these files from the Asset>Plugins folder and everything worked[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTxyN.png)

Answer (score 0):

To the guys who are facing this issue pls try to reimport your assets. In Assets (Tab) > Reimport hope this will solve your issue.